# I am deploying react app through my GitHub on Heroku but its showing error

Tags: reactjs, heroku

```
 -----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! code EUSAGE
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's ajv@6.12.6 does not satisfy ajv@8.11.0
       npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
       npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 does not satisfy json-schema-traverse@1.0.0
       npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
       npm ERR! Missing: typescript@4.8.4 from lock file
       npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
       npm ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
       npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
       npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
       npm ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
       npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
       npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
       npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
       npm ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
       npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
       npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Clean install a project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Usage:
       npm ERR! npm ci
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Options:
       npm ERR! [--no-audit] [--foreground-scripts] [--ignore-scripts]
       npm ERR! [--script-shell <script-shell>]
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.eeeVc/_logs/2022-10-08T16_54_25_418Z-debug-0.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: `Please update your lock file with npm install before continuing. `

Comment: sorry but I m just a beginner, could you please tell me where exactly I have to put in the package-lock.json file

Comment: 1. Run `npm install` 2. Commit 3. Push

Comment: sorry it did not work

Comment: https://github.com/Siddhant-Kashyap/myPortfolio

Comment: this is my gitlink of repo this i m deploying but its showing that error

Comment: @SiddhantKashyap, please read [ask]. "It did not work" is not very useful feedback. Did `npm install` update your `package-lock.json`? Are you sure you committed and deployed the changes? Are you getting a different error message now?

Comment: Thank you! for refactoring my question . Now it worked I just added my package-lock.json in .gitignore and deployed it to Heroku it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Finally after doing a lot of hits and trials it's working now. I just added my `package-lock.json` in `.gitignore` and deployed it to Heroku it worked fine.